# Is there nsiClientSocket in firefox extension javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

How to connect to a port from javascript in firefox extensions? I could able to open the port and listen (Server side socket), but I want the Client side socket which will connect to server (Port opened in java).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use [nsISocketTransportService.createTransport()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsISocketTransportService#createTransport%28%29). Something like this should work:

```js
var transport = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/socket-transport-service;1"]
                          .getService(Components.interfaces.nsISocketTransportService)
                          .createTransport(null, 0, host, port, null);
var stream = transport.openOutputStream(0, 0, 0);
var data = "test";
stream.write(data, data.length);
stream.close();
```

All connection events happen asynchronously so in order to listen to transport events you need to call [`transport.setEventSink()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsITransport#setEventSink%28%29):

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm");
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
transport.setEventSink({
  onTransportStatus: function(transport, status, progress, progressMax)
  {
    ...
  },
  QueryInterface: XPCOMUtils.generateQI([Components.interfaces.nsITransportEventSync])
}, Services.tm.currentThread);
```

For reference: [nsITransportEventSink](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsITransportEventSink), [nsITransportEventSink status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsISocketTransport#InterfacensITransportEventSink_status_codes.)

Comment: Thnx..this is working. If the port is not listening at server then no exception is thrown. How could i catch those exceptions?