# Capture DNS requests by nsISocketTransportService

Tags: javascript, browser, dns, firefox-addon

I want to write a browser extension for firefox to capture DNS requests that are sent from client browser to the server. So when a webpage is opened I want to capture all DNS requests which are sent from browser. I found this class ***nsISocketTransportService*** in this question: [Is there nsiClientSocket in firefox extension javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850258/is-there-nsiclientsocket-in-firefox-extension-javascript). But I'm not sure if it's what I need or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot observe DNS requests in Firefox as they are issued (which has nothing to to with `nsISocketTransportService` BTW).

The only work around I can imagine that does not involve hooking `nsIDNSService`/`gethostname` (which isn't really a reliable option either):

- Observe [`http-on-modify-request`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Observer_Notifications#HTTP_requests)
- Do the lookup yourself using [`nsIDNSService`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/dns/nsIDNSService.idl)

This of course won't work for ftp or raw TCP connections. And there is no guarantee that subsequent calls during the actual connection setup will receive the same (cached) response later.
So even the work around is pretty bad.

Comment: thanks, do you know if it is possible to capture dns request in chrome?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, and it honestly would surprise me... But then again I'm not really fluent in Chrome extension development.